# React: Data not showing until I search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

I have a react component that serve to search a name in a table.
Everything is working fine, except that I have to search first in order to see data. If I land on the page without a search I will not have information.

How do I display data first and then search in it ? I'm using React and Laravel for API.

My JS code:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Widget1 from "../components/Widget1";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
import { Container, Dropdown, ListGroup, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { Table, Thead, Tbody, Tr, Th, Td } from "react-super-responsive-table";
import "react-super-responsive-table/dist/SuperResponsiveTableStyle.css";
import { useState } from "react";

function SearchPatient() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  async function search(key) {
    console.warn(key);
    let result = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/search/" + key);
    result = await result.json();
    console.warn(result);
    setData(result);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Search</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Search"
            id="nom"
            onChange={(e) => search(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>

        <Table className="table table-hover">
          <Thead className="thead-light text-center">
            <Tr>
              <Th>N°</Th>
              <Th style={{ width: "6%" }}>NOM</Th>
              <Th>PRÉNOM</Th>
            </Tr>
          </Thead>
          <Tbody className="text-center">
            {data.map((patient) => (
              <Tr>
                <Td style={{ verticalAlign: "middle" }} className="text-muted">
                  <b>{patient.id}</b>
                </Td>
                <Td style={{ verticalAlign: "middle" }}>{patient.nom} </Td>
                <Td style={{ verticalAlign: "middle" }}>{patient.prenom} </Td>
              </Tr>
            ))}
          </Tbody>
        </Table>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchPatient;

if (document.getElementById("SearchPatient")) {
  ReactDOM.render(<SearchPatient />, document.getElementById("SearchPatient"));
}
```

API :

```
Route::get('/search/{key}/', [PatientController::class, 'search']);
```

Laravel Controller :

```
public function search($key)
{
    return Patient::where('nom','Like',"%$key%")->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load data to show it, and you are not doing it. You need to run side effect on component render to get initial data. If your search with empty `key` yields all data, you need single effect for everything, and you will need two effects, if initial data are loaded somehow else.

### With empty search returning all data:

```js
// We store current search value here and changing this state variable will rerun side effect
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

async function getSearchResult(key, signal) {
  let result = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/search/" + key, {
    signal,
  });
  result = await result.json();
  setData(result);
}

// Effect will fire on first render and whenever `search` variable changes
useEffect(
  function () {
    // We need AbortController to prevent race condition when user is sending one request after another
    // Since you are firing this on every keystroke, it is advisable to either debounce, or throttle your search
    let controller = new AbortController();
    let signal = controller.signal;
    getSearchResult(search, signal).catch((error) => {
      // Handling errors, especially with promises is very important
      console.error(error);
    });
    return () => controller.abort();
  },
  [search]
);

<div className="form-group">
  <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Search</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    className="form-control"
    placeholder="Search"
    id="nom"
    onChange={(event) => setSearch(event.target.value)}
  />
</div>;
```

### With different request for initial data:

```js
// We store current search value here and changing this state variable will rerun side effect
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

async function getSearchResult(key, signal) {
  let result = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/search/" + key, {
    signal,
  });
  result = await result.json();
  setData(result);
}

// Effect will fire on first render and whenever `search` variable changes
useEffect(
  function () {
    // We will opt out if search is not empty
    if (search !== "") return;
    let controller = new AbortController();
    let signal = controller.signal;
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/intial_data", {
      signal,
    })
      .then((result) => result.json())
      .then((result) => setData(result))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    return () => controller.abort();
  },
  [search]
);

// Effect will fire on first render and whenever `search` variable changes
useEffect(
  function () {
    // We will opt out if search is empty
    if (search === "") return;
    // We need AbortController to prevent race condition when user is sending one request after another
    // Since you are firing this on every keystroke, it is advisable to either debounce, or throttle your search
    let controller = new AbortController();
    let signal = controller.signal;
    getSearchResult(search, signal).catch((error) => {
      // Handling errors, especially with promises is very important
      console.error(error);
    });
    return () => controller.abort();
  },
  [search]
);

<div className="form-group">
  <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Search</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    className="form-control"
    placeholder="Search"
    id="nom"
    onChange={(event) => setSearch(event.target.value)}
  />
</div>
```

Notice the `AbortController`. It is important that every subsequent request will cancel out previous, since you may end up getting wrong data, if previous request will finish after next one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailled explanation. Still beginner in react and already managed to understand the problem. For now when i'm trying to display data I have the following error `search.map is not a function`, I replaced search instead of patient in my code.

Comment: I guess it's because useState is not an array ?

Comment: What is search and why are you mapping it? In my example `search` is a string

Comment: In order to display data in a table. In the example you provided I don't know how you displayed the retrieved data. In my case I was using it on an array.

Comment: But why are you iterating over `search` and not over `data`? All code outside of effects, new state variable `search` and event handler on `input` remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the data inside the `useEffect` hook. You can read more about [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) but in simple words, you use it to *do something* when your component mounts.

You can add this `useEffect` line after your useState hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let result = await fetch(/* Your get request */);
  result = await result.json();
  setData(result)
}, [])
```

and the empty array indicates that you want to run this, once, when your component mounts. I strongly recommend reading more about `useEffect` and the dependency array

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing this is because the default state you have set is a empty array.

You did this when you made this definition

```
 const [data,setData]=useState([]);
```

So to have some default data you want to call an endpoint to return the default data you want to see using the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook. You can also see it as a mechanism that triggers a side effect as a result of a state change.

See a snippet below of what your code should look like.

```
// 
useEffect(() => {
    //Initial API call with default results
    //Set data with API results
}, [data]); 
//data controls when the component updates, so when you call you call the search function, it'll cause a change to the data value and trigger the `useEffect` hook.
```

Learn more with this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZJgIjIuY7U)

Comment: This will fire constantly, since it will change data, render, request new data, set new data and so on